# .Net Core 2.2 Web API getting 415 Unsupported Media type on a GET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have upgraded my WebApi project to .net core 2.2 and since then, all of my controllers are pulling 415 Unsupported Media type from every single GET call. Which is super strange because 415 is generally something reserved for POST in my experience.

If I downgrade back to 2.1, problem goes away. I've posted code below of my controller setup, and the basic startup config.

```
    [Route("v1/[controller]")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    [Authorize]
    public class JobsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetJobSummaryByUserId([FromQuery] PagedJobRequest pagedJobRequest)
        {
            if (pagedJobRequest.UserId == Guid.Empty)
            {
                pagedJobRequest.UserId = _jwtUtility.GetIdentityId();
            }
            if (!_jwtUtility.DoesJwtIdentityIdMatch(pagedJobRequest.UserId) && !_jwtUtility.IsUserInRole("Administrator"))
            {
                return Unauthorized();
            }

            var returnObj = _jobsService.GetJobSummariesByUserId(pagedJobRequest);

            return Ok(returnObj);
        }
}
```

In Startup.cs:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddCors(x => x.AddPolicy("MVRCors", y => y.AllowCredentials().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin()));
        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
        }
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(s =>
            {
                s.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MVR.Api.Jobs");
            });
        }

        ConfigureExceptionHandling(app);
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseCors("MVRCors");

        loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
    }
```

Comment: Look in "Chrome Developer Tools > Network" (or equivalent).  Q: What is the HTTP "Accept" header in your GET request?  Q: What is the HTTP "Content-Type" in the response?

Comment: am using postman, where ive never needed to specify any of that before pre-2.2 but let me try

Comment: We just want to see "who's falling down" - the client, or the controller.  Looking at the send/receieve HTTP headers will help us determine that.  PS: Why bother with Postman, if you're using Swagger?  Just curious...

Comment: well swagger security definitions arent taking bearer tokens, another fun change that came with upgrading to latest. Our controllers are fully JWT Authorized

Comment: Drag - one step forward, two steps back :(  ANYWAY - I'm really curious what you see in the "accept" request and "Content-Type" response headers.  Please keep us posted!

Answer (score 7):

It is a known issue with 2.2

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4396

It appears that [this bug fix](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8174) in 2.2 caused any `GET` requests to honour the `[Consumes]` attribute on a controller. Previously, in 2.1, they did not.

The workaround is to remove the `[Consumes]` attribute from the controller and apply it only to non-`GET` methods in your controller, or downgrade and keep using .NET Core 2.1 until they release a fix.

It has [already been fixed](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/pull/4459) for the 3.0 .NET Core release. I think they are still deciding if they will fix it in a 2.2 service release.

Comment: @willthiswork89: Boy, I'm glad I'm still on 2.1 ;)  I'm still curious what your "Accept" headers were (I imagine "application/json") and the corresponding "Content-Type" response header. Please do post this info, when you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `[FromQuery]` to `[FromForm]` in your controller.

Answer (score -1):

Set the content type in postman to:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Setting a content type on a GET will cause the framework to expect an non-empty body and result in another error.